# how to use k fold cross validation for image classification using cnn

Tags: classification

how can i use  k fold cross validation for  validate my model ?

I don't know what commands to add and where to add them for validation

I don't have more explanations. Don't hang around anymore, let me post my questionnnnnnn

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
#from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tqdm import tqdm
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
import os 

DATADIR ='D:/Seminar/dataset1.0.1  the-circor-digiscope-phonocardiogram/AV/'

df = pd.read_csv('D:/Seminar/dataset1.0.1  the-circor-digiscope-phonocardiogram/AV.csv')  
print(df.head())     # printing first five rows of the file
print(df.columns)


SIZE = 224
X_dataset = []  
for i in tqdm(range(df.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img(DATADIR +str(df['id'][i])+'_AV.png', target_size=(SIZE,SIZE,3))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255.
    X_dataset.append(img)
   
    X = np.array(X_dataset)
    
    #y_train = np.asarray(df).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
    #y_test = np.asarray(df).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
    
    
    y = np.array(df.drop(['id', 'status'], axis=1))

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=20, test_size=0.3)
    

    
    model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation="relu", input_shape=(SIZE,SIZE,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=100)


#plot the training and validation accuracy and loss at each epoch
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs = range(1, len(loss) + 1)
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'y', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'y', label='Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I did not try anything! I am waiting for someone to help me

I don't know what commands to add and where to add them for validation

I don't have more explanations. Don't hang around anymore, let me post my questionnnnnnn